# "Address already in use" even though setReuseAddress(true)

Tags: java, serversocket

Even though I call `ServerSocket.setReuseAddress(true)`, I still get `java.net.BindException: Address already in use` on *some* machines if the port has been recently used.

```
InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(13025);
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();         
serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
serverSocket.bind(isa, 50);
```

My understanding [from the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setReuseAddress(boolean)) is that the reuse flag will ensure that the port can be bound to, even though the port may be in a `TIME_WAIT` state.

Is there some way around this?  Is there a kernel setting for this, since it only happens on some (older and probably slower) machines.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't because the port is still in LISTEN state?

Comment: Two questions: 1) Which platform are you trying this in, and 2) when you say "the port has been recently used" do you mean by the same process or by a new process?

Comment: @EJP `netstat -pant` reports it's in a `TIME_WAIT` state just before I get the connection error.

Comment: @MikeLaren (1) Ubuntu 13.04 (2) By a new process

Comment: That would have to be a kernel bug if true.

Comment: @EJP I'll try a reinstall and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: @EJP I think you were correct about the port still being in the listen state.  I reworked my code to guarantee that the port is always closed, and this error seems to have disappeared.  If you submit this as an answer, I'll accept.